# Executing a function send with a variable

Tags: jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, typeof

I have following code

```
if(data.title != false) {
    $('#modal').find('.modal-header h3').html(data.title);
}
if(data.buttons != false) {
    $.each(data.buttons, function(i, button){
        $('.modal-footer').append('<button class="btn" id="btn_'+button.text+'">'+button.text+'</button>');

        if(jQuery.type(button.click) === 'function') {
            console.log('jQuery says it is a function')
            $('.modal-footer').off('click', '#btn_'+button.text).on('click', '#btn_'+button.text, button.click());
        }
    });
}
```

It is part of a function which is used to open a bootstrap modal (dialog).
I was trying to add the abbility to add custom buttons to the modal like jQuery has on their dialogs.

I send it like this:

```
makeBootstrapModal({
    buttons: [
        {
            text:'OK',
            click: function() {
                $('#modal').modal('close');
            }
        },
        {
            text:'Annuleren',
            click: function() {
                $('#modal').modal('close');
            }
        },
    ],
    title: 'Hallo',
});
```

The title gets added properly and in the console I know button.click is a function when I check it, but when I try to add it as a click event I get the following error:

```
TypeError: data[option] is not a function   

if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
```

It's the first time I use a function like this. Does anyone know how to make this work ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. As I am used to jQuery dialogs I put `close` as modal function. The Bootstrap modal only takes `hide` as function to close it again. Now it works great.